# Azure performance issue of .NET MVC 5 website - latency?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

We're seeing some major issues with the performance of our MVC 5 website. When I do a lightweight performance test of our website (PAAS) with around 15-20 request/sec on a single, basic page, the performance tools (I use both JMeter and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 RC) report around 500ms response time per request. Also the IIS logs also report around 500ms per request. Note that during these test I only use 1 S2 instance.

The strange thing is though, that Application Insights report that these requests have a response time of around 150ms, so I've "lost" around 350ms. The response of these pages are small, only around 10KB, so I really do not expect 350ms for data transfer etc.

I've also added custom logging using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to hook into various stages of my request lifecycle. After looking at [this](http://i1.asp.net/media/4773381/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application.pdf?cdn_id=2015-05-22-001) diagram, I started my Stopwatch in my custom `ControllerFactory.CreateController` method and stop it in my `Controller.OnResultExecuted` method, which I think covers the complete request. This is backed up by the fact that the Stopwatch' elapsed time is more or less the same as the response time reported by Application Insights. I'm missing the exact same 350ms here!

Some additional info:
- The page I test is a simple page without an external webservice or database
- The CPU usage stays low throughout the test, max around 30%
- The site is hosted in West Europe which is supposedly Amsterdam. When testing locally I expect very low latency as I live 40 miles away.
- I've done a test from Azure North Europe with the same results

I have the feeling that something is being throttled, as CPU is low, but response times are high. I don't know Azure well enough to know what and where. I would appreciate every advice. Thanks!

Comment: You could be loosing time on the DNS lookup - try it against pingdom tools and you will be able to see the breakdown of where the time is going - http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ (Be sure to choose amsterdam under the settings drop-out

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have fixed it in the meanwhile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging further, it seemed that while constructing certain services and controllers, we would read application settings using the `WebConfigurationManager`.

It turns out this is **slow** on Azure. As you can overwrite your hardcoded config settings in the Azure Management Portal, each lookup to a setting does some internal call to see if this setting is overridden.

Now this is might not be the biggest performance issue if you have little traffic on your site and you do this only once for each request, as this might take - say - 15ms for each lookup. But if you do this 7 times for each request (we have a lot of credentials for various API's, domain settings, all of which are configurable), and you have 100 reqs/sec, well, do the math. It kills the performance of your site. We now write these settings to some Singleton settings object and performance has increased drastically.

This also explains the reason why CPU was low, as it is waiting for some external call to complete. The CPU is doing nothing.